# A method that dismisses a `modalViewController` and presents another

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

The thing is: I have a `modalViewController` presented with a button that triggers an IBAction like this:

```
-(IBAction)myMethod
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(presentOtherModalView)])
    {
        [delegate presentOtherModalView];
    } 
}
```

in the root view that is the delegate for that `modalViewController`I've implemented the `presentOtherModalView` delegate method and it looks like this:

```
    -(void)presentOtherModalView
{

     AnotherViewController *viewInstance = [[AnotherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];

     viewInstance.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

     [self presentModalViewController:viewInstance animated:YES];

    [viewInstance release];
}
```

The problem is this second `modalViewController` is not being presented. It gives me the message `wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003`... How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are executed exactly after each other (they don't wait for the view to disappear/appear), it doesn't get executed. Because there can only be one ModalViewController on the screen at a time, you have to first wait for the other ModalViewController to disappear before the next one is put on screen.

You can do this creatively how you want, but the way I did it was something like:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.isModalViewControllerNeeded = YES;
```

And then in the underlying ViewController, in the viewDidAppear method, I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.isModalViewControllerNeeded) {
        [self presentModalViewController:viewInstance animated:YES];
        self.isModalViewControllerNeeded = NO;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is the `isModalViewControllerNeeded ` ?

Comment: Just an example of a BOOL property. You could make up your own.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` takes some time to dismiss with animation and you are calling another view to present as modal view before dismissing the 1st modal view so the presenting modal view call was rejected. You should not perform animations when you are not on the view after completely dismissing only you can call another view. To solve this problem call the present modal view after 2 or 3 seconds using time interval or use completion block for `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`

You can achieve it by using this

```
[delegate performSelector:@selector(presentOtherModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

Comment: How could I do it using time interval?

Comment: It gives me the warning of method `performSelector: withObject afterDelay` `not found`

Comment: This however, is not really a solid way to do it in my opinion. What if the dismissing takes longer (on slower devices)? Or what if it takes less time? Then the user gets the underlying interface and doesn't know he has to wait for the next view to come up.

Comment: You need to cast the delegate object to the actual class you are working in order to have the methods. Seen the delegate only can only show the methods defined in the protocol. performSelector:withObject: is not a method defined in the protocol.
`[(CurrentClass*)delegate performSelector:@selector(presentOtherModalView) withObject:myObject afterDelay:3.0];`